# Smartsheet API: Update formula value in sheet

Tags: smartsheet-api, alteryx, smartsheet-api-2.0

I'm trying to update a a cell with an existing formula in a Smartsheet sheet. I've read in a similar topic that this is now possible but can't work out how to get that done through my json parse.

Currently this following string type is converted to JSON (using Alteryx) with HTTP Action = PUT

```
{"id": "111111111111111", "cells": [ {"columnId": 11111111111111111, "value": "=[Actual.]6}" ] }
```

Using this I'm successfully updating the sheet cell to "=[Actual.]6", BUT it comes in as Text and a single quotation mark to disable the formula function eg. '=[Actual.]6. I've tried to parse the value without quotation marks, but that didn't work at all...

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to set a formula, you should use the formula property :

```
{"id": "111111111111111", "cells": [ {"columnId": 11111111111111111, "formula": "=[Actual.]6}" ] }
```

Comment: Thanks, I even thought about trying this but thought this would be way to simple after reading this: "The main difference is to set the formula in the row object instead of setting the value."  This makes a bit more sense now but a simpler way of describing it would be "Simply replace "value" with "formula" in the JSON string. Thanks for your help to solve this!